# How To Avoid Function Redefinition in Shared Libraries ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am writing an open source iOS library in Objective-C that I eventually intend to upload to github.  My library depends on and defines certain functions, say for example...

```
CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees);
UIColor RGB(int r, int g, int b);
```

This is all fine HOWEVER when someone adds my library to their project if they too have defined a `DegreesToRadians` or `RGB` function, or they're using another library that defines them, then there will be a `Redfinition of DegreesToRadians` compile error.

Is there anyway I am able to organise the definition of my functions, use appropriate keywords, use #ifndef somehow, move #import statements, or any other solution so that the functions only effectively exist internally in my library and are not exposed outside and therefore don't cause a conflict?

CAVEATS:

- I would prefer not to prefix my functions as these get used extensively internally and would spoil the semantics and readability of my code.
- I am aware I could define the functions 'static' and with-in the class(es) that use them but these function's are used within many classes and so this approach would violate the DRY principle.
- In an ideal world the user doesn't want to modify my libraries code to avoid this error so having the user just comment out the definitions in my library code or the other potential conflicting libraries code is unacceptable.

Comment: do you want those function to be used by others?

Comment: Ideally yes but only if they need to (i.e. they could manually import). However I'd still be interested in solutions that don't allow use of the functions.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way you could do it is to include those function definitions in private header files.

Add the `.h` where they are defined into the "private headers" section of the library configuration. Then they will not be visible to users using your library.

If you want to expose them, but are still worried about clashes, why don't you move them into classes? I know they're different functions, but you could move them into classes as functions of an object e.g.

```
MyConverter
- (CGFloat)radiansFromDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees;
```

Then users can use your class to do the same things if they wish, or extend the functionality if they want to change it. Your library will still use the class you created, so there should be no crossed wires.

Comment: The private header part sounds reasonable, but what happens if the user of the library has functions with the same signature in his code? Wouldn't that cause a duplicate symbol error during linking?

Comment: The reason I don't use methods is because they're used thousands of times and would massively increase code size and decrease readability.

Comment: @rsanchezsaez It should be alright. Libraries load top down, so the library won't have visibility on any functions that the user has created (goes without saying) and if the library doesn't expose the function then there should be no clash with the end app. If its not exposed publicly then there will be no linker issues.

Comment: @HaggleLad I disagree. Using classes may marginally increase code size, but not much. Readability will more than definitely be increased as will maintainability. Keeping things in contextual classes (e.g. conversions in a conversion class, colours in a colour class etc) will make the code much nicer to read and maintain in the future. Plus it will make it 100x nicer for people to use when they download your library to use in their app.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with "private header" files, how does that work?

Comment: @HaggleLad http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Setting%20the%20Role%20of%20a%20Header%20File.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH9-SW1

Comment: From that link you're probably after "project" instead of "private": "The symbols are not visible to clients at all, only to you."

Comment: @ThomasClayson Good stuff! Cheers for the clarifications and excuse my competing answer. :-)

Comment: Right so that's a project specific setting and thus if the end user is just downloading my library source code and adding it to their project that is an additional step they would have to take to get the library working?

Comment: There is no additional step. Basically, think about a class. If you have a class which is only used in your `.m` files in your library (i.e. its only used in your library) then you can add the `.h` to the "project" bit in your library config. This will make it available in your library, but not available outside of your library. When you export the library you will see those header files don't get included in the finished package.

Comment: From the comment of @HaggleLad, Ideally, he wants the functions to be able to be used by others. Beside making a helper class, is there a better way to do so?

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either you want to hide the functions from the user or you want to give them access. If you want to give them access to the functions, but the names are so generic that its likely that they will be in use separately by other devs then you have to deal with that by either using helper classes or by "namespacing" your functions. (No namespacing in objc means you'll just have to put a prefix on the function). As long as the library is well documented anyway there shouldn't be a problem with any of it.

Comment: Last thought: if I had a function (or class or anything) which "clashed" with an external library then I would just refactor the name of my method. I prefix everything I do anyway (with my initials usually) to minimise the risk of clashes. E.g. the class `DialogView` might clash with something somewhere. So I would call it `TCDialogView` and I can be a bit more sure that its not going to clash with anything. I would do this whether I'm creating a library or an app (and using 3rd party libraries).

Answer (score 1):

Despite you wanting to avoid this solution, I suspect that the easiest one would be adding a sufficiently unique prefix to the name of these functions (given that neither C nor Objective-C have *namespaces*).

If you want to improve readability of your code, you can then add the following macro in a private header:

```
#define DegreesToRadians() HLDegreesToRadians()
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your function implementations in a header file and declare them as static.

Eg:

```
static UIColor *RGB(int r, int g, int b) {
   // blah...
}
```

The name `RGB` won't be exported from the compilation unit that includes the header, so you won't run into linker errors if the same name is used elsewhere.

Impact on code size will be minimal so long as your functions are small.
Otherwise, you could call through into a properly prefixed function from your static function.

Nice thing about this vs. using a macro is that autocomplete still works properly and there's no weirdness with commas.

Answer (score 0):

> I would prefer not to prefix my functions as these get used extensively internally and would spoil the semantics and readability of my code.

Just prefix what is globally visible (or namespace if you are using C++).

> I am aware I could define the functions 'static' and with-in the class(es) that use them but these function's are used within many classes and so this approach would violate the DRY principle.

These are both likely to be one-liners. Just put them in a private header and declare them `static`. You can then import this header in your `*.m` files. There is no need for the clients to see these, and because they are `static` you can omit the prefix.